Email from Azure using SendGrid
I have an APP on Azure that if I run locally from my laptop using CMD runs perfectly and will use the send email function. I can also run an email test using BASH and the email is sent instantly. Now the issue if I use the desktop/home screen version of the APP everything works except the send email function. Relevant Parts of Code (Python)
# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')

- def send_email(to_email, subject, content):
- message = Mail(
- from_email='App@My Domain.com',  # Use your verified email address
- to_emails=to_email,
- subject=subject,
- plain_text_content=content
-     )
- try:
- sg = SendGridAPIClient(SENDGRID_API_KEY)
- response = sg.send(message)
- print('Status Code:', response.status_code)
- print('Body:', response.body.decode('utf-8') if response.body else '')  # Ensure body is in readable format
- print('Headers:', response.headers)
- except Exception as e:
- if hasattr(e, 'body'):
- print('Error Body:', e.body.decode('utf-8'))  # Ensure body is in readable format
- else:
- print('Error:', str(e))

From App Rout:
print(f"Sending email to xyz@MY Domain.com with subject: {email_subject}")
                print(f"Email content: {email_content}")

                try:
                    send_email('xyz@My Domain.com', email_subject, email_content)
                    flash('Project submitted for quote successfully.', 'success')
                except Exception as e:
                    flash(f'Project submitted for quote successfully, but email notification failed: {e}', 'warning')

                return redirect(url_for('welcome'))

Test that runs from BASH:#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash

API_KEY="Send Grid Key"
EMAIL_TO="xyz@My Domain.com"
EMAIL_FROM="app@my domain.com"
SUBJECT="Test Email from Azure"
CONTENT="This is a test email from your Azure app."

curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "personalizations": [
      {
        "to": [
          {
            "email": "'"$EMAIL_TO"'"
          }
        ],
        "subject": "'"$SUBJECT"'"
      }
    ],
    "from": {
      "email": "'"$EMAIL_FROM"'"
    },
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "text/plain",
        "value": "'"$CONTENT"'"
      }
    ]
  }'

I am at a loose as to why the app won't send an email from the Azures default domain. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Hoping to get my App running correctly.

The issues you encounter during the deployment to Azure likely due to the differences in environment configurations between your local setup and Azure.Here’s below steps to ensure your Function can send emails using SendGrid, along with the necessary configurations:
You need to store your SendGrid API key in the environment variables.

Local development: Use a .env file to store your API key.

SENDGRID_API_KEY=your_sendgrid_api_key_here


Azure: Set the application settings in the Azure portal.


I Followed this link to Send Email with Microsoft Azure  with  SendGrid
Add sender:


Create API keys and replace all the details



I also used this link and git to learn how to send email with Python in SendGrid.

Here is a sample Python script using Flask and SendGrid:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email, To, Content

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    return "Welcome to the email sending app!"

@app.route('/send-email', methods=['POST'])
def send_email():
    try:
        sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
        
        data = request.get_json()
        from_email = Email(data.get('from_email'))  
        to_email = To(data.get('to_email'))          
        subject = data.get('subject')
        content = Content("text/plain", data.get('content'))
        
        mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)
        
        response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
        
        return jsonify({
            'status_code': response.status_code,
            'headers': dict(response.headers),
            'body': response.body.decode('utf-8')
        })
    
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)



Set Up Your Environment Variable with .env file:
SENDGRID_API_KEY=your_sendgrid_api_key_here

requirements.txt:
python-dotenv
sendgrid
Flask

Set Up a Virtual Environment:
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate 


Local Output:

with  below return in /send-email
return  f"Send email to xyz@yourdomain.com with subject: {email_subject}"



I followed this MSDOC to deploy a Python (Flask) web app to Azure - Azure App Service.
Deployed status of the app in Visual Studio Code:

Azure Web App Output:


